# Using this code to send email using C# but not working

Tags: c#

This is the code that is not working. Can anyone suggest how to make it work?

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
        mailMsg.To.Add("ashishbhatt1501@.com");

        string from = email.Text;
        MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress(from);
        mailMsg.From = mailAddress;


        mailMsg.Subject = "subject";
        mailMsg.Body = comments.Text;


        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
           new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail", "password");
        smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;

        smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
        Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Mail sent thank you...');if(alert){ window.location='SendMail.aspx';}</script>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: The email address you have: `ashishbhatt1501@.com` is not valid.

Comment: First I'd fix that email address in the To field. "ashishbhatt1501@.com" is not a valid email address.

Comment: done with editing but the code is still not working..

Comment: First set `UseDefaultCredentials = false;` then set the credentials.

Comment: enableSsl="true" .. this is showing an error that this is not defined . this error is occuring in web.config file

Comment: another error is           Exception Details: System.FormatException: The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.

Source Error:


Line 21: protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 22: {
Line 23:     MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
Line 24:     var emailsender = email.Text ;
Line 25:     msg.From = new MailAddress(emailsender);

Answer (score 0):

Email format isn't valid. I'd suggest run your email string thru regular expression and execute the rest of the code only if RegEx returns true.

```
var regex = new Regex("\w[-._\w]*\w@\w[-._\w]*\w\.\w{2,3}");
if (regex.Match("abd@abd.com")){
    do something .... 
}
```